# Не отображается виджет сдэк

Tags: php, django, cdek

Хотел подключить на сайт виджет сдэк для выбора пункта выдачи. При загрузке страницы отображается пустой место.
Сайт написан на django

head

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Confirm</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp1/styles/confirm.css' %}">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'myapp1/images/favicon_io/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'myapp1/images/favicon_io/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'myapp1/images/favicon_io/favicon-16x16.png' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'myapp1/libs/inputmask.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp1/files/pvzwidget/widget/widjet.js' %}" id="ISDEKscript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var widjet = new ISDEKWidjet({
            defaultCity: 'Уфа',
            cityFrom: 'Омск',
            link: 'forpvz'
        });
     </script>
```

контейнер виджета на странице

```
<div id="forpvz" style="height:600px;"></div>
```

параметры в servece.php

```
SDEKService\Controller::processRequest(
        SDEKService\Settings::factory(
            /** Настройте приоритет тарифов курьерской доставки */
            /** Set up the priority of courier delivery tariffs */
            array(233, 137, 139, 16, 18, 11, 1, 3, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 83),
            /** Настройте приоритет тарифов доставки до пунктов выдачи */
            /** Set the priority of delivery tariffs to pick-up points */
            array(234, 136, 138, 15, 17, 10, 12, 5, 62, 63),
            /** Вставьте свой аккаунт\идентификатор для интеграции */
            /** Put your account for integration here */
            'тут актуальный идентификатор',
            /** Вставьте свой пароль для интеграции */
            /** Put your password for integration here */
            'тут актуальный пароль'
        )
    );
```

версия php

PHP 8.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2023 12:35:15) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

curl вроде как установлен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли сайта ошибок нет, контейнер пуст.

консоль сервера

```
[19/Aug/2023 20:05:30] "GET /confirm HTTP/1.1" 200 10745
[19/Aug/2023 20:05:31] "GET /static/myapp1/files/pvzwidget/widget/widjet.js HTTP/1.1" 200 84852
[19/Aug/2023 20:05:31] "GET /static/myapp1/libs/inputmask.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 115710
[19/Aug/2023 20:05:31] "GET /static/myapp1/files/pvzwidget/widget/scripts/service.php?isdek_action=getLang&lang=rus HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[19/Aug/2023 20:05:31] "GET /static/myapp1/files/pvzwidget/widget/scripts/service.php?isdek_action=getPVZ&country=all&lang=rus&mode=all HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[19/Aug/2023 20:05:31] "GET /static/myapp1/js/confirm.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```